# Support api versioning outside the api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

#### The situation

I'm currenty working on a project that contains an api (ASP.NET Core API, .NET6), a client (.NET6) for that api and a library (.NET6) with classes and interfaces for both other projects. Now I realised that at some point I will have to publish a new version of api and client to provide new features or bug fixes. So api versioning with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` would be the next to implement.

#### The problem

If the user installs a new update for the client **BEFOR** the new version of the api is installed, the user would not be able to use the system until everything is up to date. I look for some guides to implement api versioning and found only helpful thinks for the api project.

#### Question

I would like to follow [this guid](https://www.ezzylearning.net/tutorial/how-to-support-multiple-versions-of-asp-net-core-web-api) for versioning my api project. But how do I implement this for my client? I want it to support older versions aswell. Are there any best practices or standards tu use? I can imagine that something with dependency injection will to the trick but I'm not very educated about this topic.

Comment: In the ideal, you make your server (previous and new version) version tolerant. If you have a new client make a request to an old server, you return a signal saying (roughly) unsupported version, try an earlier version, and the client tries with an earlier version request. If you have an old client make a request of a newer server, it should just work. Eventually, you drop support for the N-2 version. This is hard to do, and tou really have to design it in from day 1. Notice that both client and server need to be N-1 aware for this to work

Comment: If you host it on Azure you can use API Management to create a gateway. I believe it is quite expensive though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say there will be a problem if the user installed the higher version client before the higher version API. The answer is you should not release the new client before the new API is released. The new client would specify which API version to use, either by query string, header, or in the URL route. If old versions of the client did not specify an API version, you can set a default version in the API project when you add the new version, so the old client can still work. Now, from your description, it sounds like you might be installing the API project on a customer device along with the client, if that is the case then you will need to install everything at the same time, but, then using an API isn't really needed for the application.

Comment: But even when I release a new client after the api, it could be that the client update is installed earlier than the new api version or is that an overratted scenario?

Comment: The API is normally installed to a web server of some type, and it should be accessible from the network (in most cases the internet but it could be a company network) YOU will need to install the API, but your client will not. Once you update the API, the client will have access to it. The older clients can continue to use the older API version, and the new clients can use the updated API version.

Answer (score 0):

You can only request for 1 endpoint every time, either v1 or v2. So better make a switch on client to go "v1 api" or "v2 api". You could try following:
Back-end: 
v1:

```
    [Route("1.0/api/[controller]")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string test()
        {
            return "v1 result";
        }
    }
```

v2:

```
    [Route("2.0/api/[controller]")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string test()
        {         
            return "v2 result";
        }
    }
```

Front-end (MVC template):
Home controller (Change the httpclient base address depending on the cookie "version" value)

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public HomeController(HttpClient client,IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {

            this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            var version = "";
            var versioncookie = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["version"];
            if (versioncookie != null ) { version =  versioncookie+"/"; }
            else { version = "2.0/"; }   //set to 2.0 if no cookie
            
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://localhost:7006/{version}api/");  //change to your back end domain
            this._client = client;           
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var response=await _client.GetAsync("test"); //append behind the base URL
            ViewData["result"]= await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  //Show the fetch result by viewdata

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml (use radio button to change the "version" cookie to "v1" or "v2")

```
<input type="radio" id="1.0" name="version" onclick="switch1()" /> v1
<br />
<input type="radio" id="2.0" name="version" onclick="switch2()" /> v2
<br />

Fetch result is : @ViewData["result"]

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function switch1() {
        document.cookie = "version=1.0";
    }
    function switch2 (){
        document.cookie = "version=2.0";          
    } 
    document.getElementById(Cookies.get('version')).checked = true;
</script>
```

Test
[image]